# TinyTextImpl insted of String xslt

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have the below XML,

```
<outer.element>
<bold>
<csc>CSCTEXT</csc> 
REST OF THE TEXT
</bold>
</outer.element>,
```

i try to retrieve the text inside the `<outer.element>` element tag and sending it to a java method. i get the below exception,

XPathException: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of class:method() ("CSCTEXT", "REST OF THE TEXT").

if i use an array in the java method signature i get the below exception,

"Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyTextImpl of type text() to class java.lang.String"

how do i send a single concatenated value (class:method() ("CSCTEXT REST OF THE TEXT")) to the java method.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples of both the XSLT and the Java code allowing us to reproduce the problem, together with a precise description of the Saxon version used. What happens if you call the method in XSLT with `string(outer.element)` as the argument?

Comment: The diagnostic shows that you are using Saxon so I have added that as a question tag.

Answer (score 0):

The first error:

XPathException: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of class:method() ("CSCTEXT", "REST OF THE TEXT").

means that you're calling your Java method with a sequence of values when it is only expecting one.

Using collection classes in the signature of your Java method will tend to mean that the individual items don't get converted, hence the second error "Cannot convert...".

One solution to that is to do the conversion yourself in the function call (for example, by calling the data() function). Or do it in the Java method (call the getStringValue() method on the supplied items).

If I am writing extension functions in Java specifically to be called from XPath/XSLT, then I will nowadays uses Saxon-specific classes in the method signature, for example `ZeroOrMore<StringValue>`. Saxon will then use exactly the same calling conventions as it uses for native XSLT/XPath functions (for example, implicit atomization) and your called code can do any further conversion needed itself.